# Change public variable in private method using module pattern

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

I have next code:

```
var Test = (function() {
    var counter = 0;
    var increaseCounter = function() {
        this.counter += 1;
    }
    increaseCounterPrivate = function() {
        // does not affect this.counter! //
        increaseCounter();
    }
    var counterLogic = function() {
        // ... do something here ... //
        increaseCounterPrivate();
    }
    return {
        counter: counter,
        increaseCounter: increaseCounter,
        counterLogic: counterLogic
    };
});

var test = new Test();
test.increaseCounter();
console.log(this.counter); //1
test.counterLogic();
console.log(this.counter); //1 again, should be 2
```

Above code does not have sense (it's just for testing), but I want to know if in general I can call public method, which will call private method which will finally change public variable.
How this can be rewritten to display right value?

Comment: increaseCounterPrivate is in global scope, so when called by counterLogic, this refers to window.

Comment: Change line 8 to `increaseCounter.call(this);` and line 12 to `increaseCounterPrivate.call(this);`, then it should work.